# Html mouseup caching an element more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jquery script which works fine, but now I'm trying to make it into a plugin. Once it's in the plugin though, the mouseup function on the html appears to increase the cache of the same element by one every time, and I can't figure out why.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[  

    $(function(){  

              (function($) {  

              $.fn.myPlugin = function() {  

                    return this.each(function(){  

                        var $this = $(this);  

                                               $('html').mouseup(function(){            

console.log('cached +1: ' +   $this);//this ouput increases by one every mouseup                                    

                                });//html mouseup  


                            console.log('cached once: ' + $this);// this output displays once per mouseup   


                      });// return this each  


                  } //fn myPlugin  

              })(jQuery);  


    $('.box').mousedown(function(){  

        $(this).myPlugin();  

        });//.box mousedown  


    });//document ready    

    //]]>
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If someone could explain why this is happening (in as much layman's terms as possible), I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell us what you actuallywant to achieve but for a start:

Every time you click the element, `$(this).myPlugin()` gets executed.
This function itself binds an event handler to the `mouseup` event, so *every time* you click the element, a new `mouseup` event handler is added (but they are all doing the same thing).

So

1. click: `$(this).myPlugin();` gets called -> 1 `mouseup` event handler.
2. click: `$(this).myPlugin();` gets called -> 2 `mouseup` event handlers.
3. click: `$(this).myPlugin();` gets called -> 3 `mouseup` event handlers.
   etc.